# From org.json JSONObject to org.codehaus.jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to move from `org.json` to `org.codehaus.jackson`. How do I convert the following Java code?

```
private JSONObject myJsonMessage(String message){
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("message",message);
    return obj;
}
```

I left out the `try-catch` block for simplicity.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Instead of `JSONObject` use Jackson's `ObjectMapper` and `ObjectNode`:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectNode node = mapper.createObjectNode();
node.put("message", "text");
```

This would be Jackson's equivalent of your current `org.json` code.

However, where Jackson really excels is in its capacity to do complex mappings between your Java classes (POJOs) and their JSON representation, as well as its streaming API which allows you to do really fast serialization, at least when compared with `org.json`'s counterparts.

Comment: So `jacksonObj` would be my return object?

Comment: With all the hypes about jackson, I was hoping org.codehaus.jackson would be simpler than org.json. Up-vote for your help.

Comment: @kasavbere: I've edited my answer to better reflect your original question. As for simplicity, it's not really that much simple, but it depends on what you want to do with it. For simpler serializations, it's simpler to use `org.json`. However, if you are doing large object serializations, and have some custom needs (for example, serialize a `Date` field as a `String` value), Jackson is by far the best option, imho.

Comment: I know I am biased, but I don't think org.json is ever simpler, for any use, as long as one knows both APIs. With Tree Model, they are about equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

There is no `JSONObject` in Jackson api. Rather than returning a `JSONObject`, you can either return a Map or a Java Bean with message property that has getters and setters for it.

```
public class MyMessage {
    private String message;

    public void setMessage(final String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return this.message;
    }
}
```

So, your method will be reduced to:

```
private MyMessage(String message) {
    MyMessage myMessage = new MyMessage();
    myMessage.setMessage(message);
    return myMessage;
}
```

Another aspect of this change would be changing the serialization code, to convert MyMessage back to json string. Jackson does Java Beans, maps by default, you don't need to create a `JSONObject` e.g.,

```
private String serializeMessage(MyMessage message){

    //Note: you probably want to put it in a global converter and share the object mapper
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return mapper.writeValueAsString(message);
}
```

The above will return `{message: "some message"}`

I have skipped the exceptions for brevity.

Comment: With all the hypes about jackson, I was hoping org.codehaus.jackson would be simpler than org.json. Up-vote for your help.

Comment: As mentioned earlier, there is equivalent however: either `JsonNode` (base type) or `ObjectNode` (as specific JSON Object subtype). And unlike org.json, there is node inheritance for proper OO access.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to upgrade from `org.json` library to `Jackson` piece by piece, and initially retaining same API, you might want to read "[Upgrade from org.json to Jackson](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/03/entry_447.html)".
This would at least make your code about 3x faster for basic JSON reading and writing; plus you could -- if you so choose -- start converting processing, as Jackson makes it easy to convert between Trees and POJOs (`ObjectMapper.treeToValue(...)`, `valueToTree`, `convertValue` between POJOs etc. etc).

Just keep in mind that tools that you are familiar with may bias your thinking to certain patterns, and keeping an open mind can help you find even better ones.
In case of Jackson (or GSON or other mature Java JSON tools), you really should consider where proper data-binding could help, instead of using JSON-centered tree model (that org.json offers). Tree Models keep your thinking grounded to JSON structure, which is sometimes useful; but might also prevent you from seeing more natural patterns that come from defining POJO structure to reflect expected JSON, and operating on Java Objects directly.

Comment: would be a good answer if the link still worked

Comment: Link to blog seems legit?