# JSONObject sorted map params

Tags: java, json

I have a Map, which contains String keys and String and integers values.
I put values into the map as follows:

```
Map map = new LinkedHashMap();
map.put("b", 1);
map.put("a", 2);
```

After this, I added the map into a List:

```
List out = new LinkedList();
out.add(map);
```

And after that, I'm created a `JSONObject` and put the List into it:

```
org.json.JSONObject json = new org.json.JSONObject();
json.put("header", "header");
json.put("array", out);
```

But if I do this, I see this json structure:

> {"header":"header", "array":[{"a":2,"b":1}]}

But I want to see:

> {"header":"header","array":[{"b":1,"a":2}]}

Where did I go wrong? Maybe this isn't the correct way?

Comment: A `JSONObject` doesn't maintain order. So both your outputs are the same. Why do you want to see it in a particular order?

Comment: @Codebender, cause our customer want it

Comment: Make sure you create a line item for the task on his invoice. "Item 507: Meaningless reordering of JSON objects, $1200.00"

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep the order, you should not use `org.json` library as it stores the data in [HashMap](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.json/json/20141113/org/json/JSONObject.java#155), so any order you want to preserve will be ignored. There's no easy way to fix this with `org.json`. I'd suggest you to use another JSON library ([GSON](https://github.com/google/gson), [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), [minimal-json](https://github.com/ralfstx/minimal-json), etc.). Almost any other library preserves the insertion order like `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: Can you give me advice about GSON or Jackson and some light example?

Comment: @Giymose, check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12539489/4856258) for Jackson. I personally use minimal-json.

Comment: Thanks
Do you have pretty example of minimal-json?
If I want to cast this object to org.json.JSONObject - will be it correct?

Comment: @Giymose, No, you cannot cast them to org.json.JSONObject. It's better to forget about org.json and use a single alternative library only.

Answer (score 0):

No mistake. JSON by default sorts peers into alphabetical order. Because each term is explicitly named, the order makes no difference at all. "b=1" and "a=2" in both cases.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330989/order-of-serialized-fields-using-json-net) has more info.

Comment: so, I can't data into JSON in the correct sequence I need?

Comment: Short answer: No. Slightly longer: Why would you want to? It doesn't matter at all to JSON. Long answer: Yes, anything is possible. See the link above.

Comment: @TeasingDart, your link is about C# libraries which are irrelevant here. The OPs problem is about concrete org.json Java implementation, not about JSON format itself. And "default alphabetical order" is just wrong. In OPs case it's HashMap order which is unspecified and implementation-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

You can't maintain order in Map using JSONObject.

If it is feasible then I would suggest to use **`List`** (as it maintains the order) and prepare map on client side for e.g. in java script code.

Refer [Array of objects vs Object of Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31469441/array-of-objects-vs-object-of-objects)