# Kotlin http4k read response as JSONObject (org.json)

Tags: json, kotlin, jackson, http4k

As a beginner to kotlin and http4k, I am trying to read json response of a build job in jenkins. The sample code I have is as follows

```
val request = Request(Method.GET, "https://myjenkins.com/api/json")
        .header("Authorization", "Basic "+Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("username:token".toByteArray()))

val client: HttpHandler = ApacheClient()

println(client(request))
```

I am looking for a way to read the `Response` from `client(request)` as a `org.json.JSONObject` so I can just read the values from it.

I am looking for some pointers that would help me out to understand how to do this.

Comment: any particular reason you are looking for `org.json. JSONObject` ? I think Jackson's `ObjectNode` would be better Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12539571/2987755

Comment: If you are looking for Jackson's way: here is the example: https://github.com/http4k/examples/tree/master/json-api

Comment: @dkb Yes ObjectNode should be fine too, I am looking for a way to deserialise without a Data class, so if I do it as ObjectNode or JSONObject I can just pick the actual values I need. The api response on jenkins has a lot of unwanted fields, all I may need is few response fields

Comment: Great, we can do that too, but you still need to know JSON structure for the object you are interested in and convert only that JSON to Dto class and deserialize, Jackson will ignore the rest of all the fields(by setting 1 flag) or manual traverse of jsonObject is also possible

Comment: Also, you can explore: https://github.com/cdancy/jenkins-rest, if it fits your usecase.